# Different long values produce same time

Tags: java, date

I'm stumped. This makes no sense to me. The following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
long lFirst = 1383460981000L;
long lSecond = 1383464581000L;
System.out.println(lFirst);
System.out.println(lSecond);

java.util.Date first  = new Date(lFirst);
java.util.Date second = new Date(lSecond);

System.out.println(sdf.format(first));
System.out.println(sdf.format(second));

System.out.println(first.getTime());
System.out.println(second.getTime());

System.out.println("Diff" + (first.getTime() - second.getTime()));

System.out.println("Hours diff: " + (((float)(second.getTime()-first.getTime()))/1000f/60f/60f));
```

produces the following output:

```
1383460981000
1383464581000
2013-11-03 01:43:01.000
2013-11-03 01:43:01.000
1383460981000
1383464581000
Diff-3600000
Hours diff: 1.0
```

How do these two different long values produce the exact same date? I ran into this while performing a data migration from one database type to another and validating the results. I couldn't comprehend the validation failures I was seeing so I created this little snippet of code to compare the values and sure enough. While I'm willing to accept that there's some timezone weirdness going on in my databases, that would no' seem to be the issue in this code sample.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: The code does not necessarily produce that output. On my system it differs as DateFormats as well as a lot of other Java library classes have methods that depend on the current environment they are used in. To circumvent that you would have to specify timezones, charsets etc. explicitly.

Comment: What time zone are you in, or more precisely, what time zone is your computer set to?

Comment: When Daylight saving starts, time goes back one hour which means the same hour (with a different timezone) is repeated.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the moment of the daylight savings change: the time goes from 1 AM to 2 AM, and goes back to 1 AM again. So, if you add an hour to 1:43:01, you go back to 1:43:01.

Answer (score 1):

This happens during the transition from daylight savings to winter time.

Since the clocks are changed back by an hour, you get an hour's worth of timestamps that are repeated twice.

When the transition happens the other way in spring, there is an hour's worth of "missing" timestamps.